# filtering an object and displaying results to DOM (JS)

Tags: javascript, dom, foreach

```
    ***HTML***

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>ToDos</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Todos....</h1>

  <script src='todo-app.js'></script>
</body>
</html>






****JS***

const todos =[
  {
    text: 'Order Cat food',
    completed: false
  },
  {
    text: 'Clean Kitchen',
    completed: true
  },
  {
    text: 'Buy food',
    completed: true
  },
  {
    text: 'Do work',
    completed: false
  },
  {
    text: 'excercise',
    completed: false
  }
]
```

// Task
//you have 3 todos left [p element]
    // add a p for each todo above (use text value of object as visible text for paragraph)

```
*** what I have so far*****

document.createElement('p')
let pt = todos.forEach(function (t){
  if(t.completed == true){
      let pt = t

  }

})
console.log(pt)
```

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to do this challenge and got stuck. I'm trying to get the todos that are completed and display on the HTML the text of the todos then diplay the todos that were not completed (false) and display those todos as ones that need to be completed in the html as well.

I was able to filter out the todo's that have true and console log them. But I am having trouble getting out of the function and using them to display it.

when I try to call pt it says its undefined. I don't understand when it has all that code inside of it. I'm guessing I have to use the 'this' keyword which i'm still learning and don't fully understand how to implement it yet in confidence.

My question is how do I use the 'pt' varible to output the todos that are completed into the html then make another varible to output the todos that were not completed. I know to do that false todos would basically be the true todos for example

```
todos.forEach(function(f){
if(f.completed == false){
console.log(f)
*** this should return all the todo's that have the property boolean of false if i'm not mistaken.
}}
```

P.S. sorry for the confusion. And thanks for any input.

Answer (score 1):

You can break this into smaller pieces, (handling appending complete todos, and appending them) but you can do something like this:

```js
const todos = [{
    text: 'Order Cat food',
    completed: false
  },
  {
    text: 'Clean Kitchen',
    completed: true
  },
  {
    text: 'Buy food',
    completed: true
  },
  {
    text: 'Do work',
    completed: false
  },
  {
    text: 'excercise',
    completed: false
  }
]

// get element you want to append to
var completedSection = document.getElementById('completed');

function handleTodos(array, location) {
  var newArray = [];
  // loop through array
  array.forEach(function(item) {
    // check if item.completed exists
    if (item.completed) {
      // if it does, append the item to the UL that was added to html
      location.append(document.createElement("LI").innerHTML = item.text + ', ')
    } else {
      // if completed doesn't exist, push that to new array
      newArray.push(item);
    }
  });
  // return new array with incomplete tasks
  return newArray;
}

var incompleteTasks = handleTodos(todos, completedSection);

console.log(incompleteTasks)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>ToDos</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Todos....</h1>
  <!-- added to place completed tasks under, this could be created with js too. -->
  <ul id="completed"></ul>

  <script src='todo-app.js'></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps answer your question!